# Modificar Sheet killer para apenas limpar conteúdo da planilha e não apaga-la totalmente

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou utilizando o seguinte código que consegui aqui no site

```
    Sub Listar_Pastas()
    ''''''''''''''''''''
    '====  Pastas  ===='
    ''''''''''''''''''''
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim xPath As String
    Dim xWs_pastas As Worksheet
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim fso_FOLDER As Object
    Dim fso_folders As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim textoparacoluna As Object

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Janela para escolher a pasta do diretório desejado
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Escolha a pasta"
        .Show
         If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
   Else
    xPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1) & "\"

    End If
    'Alternatively, "if .selecteditems.count = 1 then myvar = .selecteditems(1)" can be used
    End With
    'On Error Resume Next
    If xPath = "" Then
        GoTo CleanExit                           'Se o caminho da pasta não existir


    End If
    'Define novo Objeto FSO GetFolder
    Set fso_FOLDER = fso.GetFolder(xPath)
    'Apaga se houver planilha com mesmo nome existente
    SheetKiller (fso_FOLDER.Name)
    'Cria nova planilha da pasta
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = fso_FOLDER.Name
    Set xWs_pastas = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(fso_FOLDER.Name)

    'https://stackoverflow.com/a/31428399/7690982
    'Encontra todos os Arquivos
    i = 3
    If fso_FOLDER.subFolders.Count > 0 Then
        'Loop em cada pasta do diretório escolhido
        For Each fso_folders In fso_FOLDER.subFolders
            With xWs_pastas
                'Preenche a coluna A com a lista de arquivos
                    .Cells(i, "A") = fso_folders.Name
                 End With
            i = i + 1
        Next fso_folders
    Else
        MsgBox "Nenhuma pasta encontrada em " & xPath
        GoTo CleanExit
    End If

     If xPath <> "" Then
     Call TextoParaColuna
    End If

    'Sair do código
CleanExit:

    Set fso = Nothing
    Set fso_FOLDER = Nothing
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "Ocorreu um erro em: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
End Sub

Public Function SheetKiller(Name As String)
    Dim s As Worksheet, t As String
    Dim i As Long, k As Long
    k = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    For i = k To 1 Step -1
        t = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
        If t = Name Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Funciona da maneira que eu tinha pedido porém preciso fazer uma modificação na parte em que ela apaga se existir uma planilha com um nome existente, até tentei algumas coisas, porém acabei criando uns erros muito estranhos que buga toda a planilha.

O que eu preciso é que quando ele detectar que a planilha já existe,não apagar ela e criar uma nova e sim limpar todo o conteúdo que ela possui e continuar com o código normalmente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue o código completo com a modificação:

```
      Sub Listar_Pastas()
    ''''''''''''''''''''
    '====  Pastas  ===='
    ''''''''''''''''''''
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim xPath As String
    Dim xWs_pastas As Worksheet
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim fso_FOLDER As Object
    Dim fso_folders As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim textoparacoluna As Object

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Janela para escolher a pasta do diretório desejado
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Escolha a pasta"
        .Show
         If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
   Else
    xPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1) & "\"

    End If
    'Alternatively, "if .selecteditems.count = 1 then myvar = .selecteditems(1)" can be used
    End With
    'On Error Resume Next
    If xPath = "" Then
        GoTo CleanExit                           'Se o caminho da pasta não existir


    End If
    'Define novo Objeto FSO GetFolder
    Set fso_FOLDER = fso.GetFolder(xPath)
    'Apaga se houver planilha com mesmo nome existente
    SheetKiller (fso_FOLDER.Name)
    'Cria nova planilha da pasta
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = fso_FOLDER.Name
    Set xWs_pastas = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(fso_FOLDER.Name)

    'https://stackoverflow.com/a/31428399/7690982
    'Encontra todos os Arquivos
    i = 3
    If fso_FOLDER.subFolders.Count > 0 Then
        'Loop em cada pasta do diretório escolhido
        For Each fso_folders In fso_FOLDER.subFolders
            With xWs_pastas
                'Preenche a coluna A com a lista de arquivos
                    .Cells(i, "A") = fso_folders.Name
                 End With
            i = i + 1
        Next fso_folders
    Else
        MsgBox "Nenhuma pasta encontrada em " & xPath
        GoTo CleanExit
    End If

     If xPath <> "" Then
     Call textoparacoluna
    End If

    'Sair do código
CleanExit:

    Set fso = Nothing
    Set fso_FOLDER = Nothing
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "Ocorreu um erro em: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
End Sub

Public Function SheetKiller(Name As String)
    Dim s As Worksheet, t As String
    Dim i As Long, k As Long
    k = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    For i = k To 1 Step -1
        t = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
        If t = Name Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Sheets(i).Cells.ClearContents
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: No caso eu não posso apagar a planilha pois isso causa um erro em uma tabela dinâmica que possuo, então as planilhas que são os meses (de 1 a 12) sempre deverão existir, porém ao clicar no macro e listar o mês 4 por exemplo, o conteúdo tem que ser apagado mas a planilha deve continuar existindo pra não estragar a tabela dinamica. Não sei se existe outra forma de fazer isso

Comment: Código alterado, agora ele vai apenas limpar a planilha desejada